# MySQL case when query returns syntax errors

Tags: mysql

Is this an illegal case when query?

It returns an error telling me to check for the right syntax to use near `votes >= ( SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*) / (2 + 1)) + 1) threshold FROM votes ) level T`. I'm running my database on MySQL 5.0.83.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (
SELECT vote_candidate, MAX(votes_above_the_threshold) votes
FROM (
SELECT vote_candidate vote_candidate, COUNT(*) votes_above_the_threshold
FROM vote_orders
WHERE vote_order = 1
GROUP BY vote_candidate
HAVING votes_above_the_threshold >= (
SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*) / (2 + 1)) + 1) threshold
FROM votes
)
) t
WHERE votes_above_the_threshold = (
SELECT MAX(votes_above_the_threshold)
FROM vote_orders
)
) votes >= (
SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*) / (2 + 1)) + 1) threshold
FROM votes
) level
THEN (level - original_votes)
ELSE 0
END redistribution
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here:

- You are selecting two columns as a scalar subquery -> select only the one you are interested in
- You are providing an alias "votes" for a scalar subquery -> remove the alias
- Similarly, you have a "level" alias for a scalar subquery later on -> remove this as well

The takeaway is that scalar subqueries should *only select a single value* and *not have an alias*.

As such, I believe the following is what you are looking for. Note the commented differences:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN (
        SELECT MAX(votes_above_the_threshold) votes
--           ^^^  *NOTE* removed "vote_candidate, "
        FROM (
            SELECT vote_candidate vote_candidate, COUNT(*) votes_above_the_threshold
            FROM vote_orders
            WHERE vote_order = 1
            GROUP BY vote_candidate
            HAVING votes_above_the_threshold >= (
                SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*) / (2 + 1)) + 1) threshold
                FROM votes
             )
        ) t
        WHERE votes_above_the_threshold = (
            SELECT MAX(votes_above_the_threshold)
            FROM vote_orders
        )
    ) >= (
--   ^^^ *NOTE* removed "votes" alias
        SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*) / (2 + 1)) + 1) threshold
        FROM votes
    )
--   ^^^ *NOTE* removed "level" alias
THEN (level - original_votes)
ELSE 0
END redistribution
```

Comment: Apparently this gave a new error: 'Every derived table must have its own alias: ...' I tried giving the last select (SELECT FLOOR...) the name u and then I returned to the inital error...

Comment: Actually - this really is the right thing. I missed some parenthesis somewhere but now it returns the value I want. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this part:

```
WHERE votes_above_the_threshold = (
SELECT MAX(votes_above_the_threshold)
FROM vote_orders
)
) votes >= (
```

to

```
WHERE votes_above_the_threshold = (
SELECT MAX(votes_above_the_threshold)
FROM vote_orders
)
and votes >= (
```

and this part is wrong:

```
) level
THEN (level - original_votes)
ELSE 0
END redistribution
```

looks like a `case when` is missing but i am not sure what that means